# AWS SES Error: Email address is not verified

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-ses

I am trying to send email using aws-sdk ses in nodejs.
While executing the code the response I am getting is:

**message:**
'Email address is not verified. The following identities failed the check in region US-EAST-1:xxxtestemailxxx@gmail.com',
**code**: 'MessageRejected'

I have already verified the sender as well as receiver email(destination email in a array).
On SES settings of aws console, it is showing the email is verified. I removed the email and then once again successfully verified it.
Last time(few months back) when I used it, everything was working fine.

Below is the screenshot of my aws console related to SES:
[image]

Also when I am sending the test email using aws console, its working fine. This is only happening when I am trying to send email using aws-sdk.
Does anyone knows what is wrong, just to be clear I am also posting the code below:

```
const send_email = function (email, subject, source, payload) {
    console.log(email, subject, source, payload);
    let email_param = {
        Destination: {
            ToAddresses: email
        },
        // ConfigurationSetName: 'XXXRANDOMTEXT_PLATFORM',
        Message: {
            Body: {
                Html: {
                    Charset: "UTF-8",
                    Data: payload
                }
                // Text: {
                //     Charset: "UTF-8",
                //     Data: payload
                // }
            },
            Subject: {
                Charset: "UTF-8",
                Data: subject
            }
        },
        Source: source
    };
    let send_email = SES.sendEmail(email_param).promise();
    send_email
        .then(data => {
            return true;
        })
        .catch(error => {
            console.log('sending email error:', error);
            return false
        });
}
```

Comment: One possibility for the email not being verified is if your are trying to invoke SES in a different region on your code. How are you enforcing the SES region when invoking?

Comment: @filipebarretto I am using the same region in aws config in which the email is verified i.e. us-east-1

Comment: is the credential from the same account ? if you're in sandbox mode, you need to verify both From and To address , also note that the email address verify in SES is case sensitive , make sure you use the exact same email (same case) in code which you have verified in console.

Comment: @JamesDean, I am using proper credentials as my whole application is using the same and working fine. Yes, I am in sandboxed mode and I have verified my TO and FROM both the email address as I have also posted the screenshot for the same. Coming the case sensitive, all the emails used are in lower case.

Comment: @Gaurav can you add the code of how you are instancing SES?

Comment: I'm in the same situation. @Gaurav, did you manage to find a solution?

Answer (score 1):

If your AWS account is still in the sandbox mode then you have to verify your sender, receiver etc. Go to the prod mod to have access to the full features.